# foreach, doParallel and random generation

Tags: r, parallel-processing, parallel-foreach, doparallel

Consider the very basic (and inefficient) code using parallel `foreach` for generating random values:

```
cl <- makeCluster(2)
registerDoParallel(cl)
foreach(i = 1:100) %dopar% rnorm(1)
```

Is it correct or are there any additional steps needed for random generation to work properly? I guess it's enough and fast checks seem to "prove" that seeds work properly, but I'd like to be sure that it is so on other platforms, since I want the code to be portable.

Comment: This collapes into two important subtasks: A: making sure parallel calls to some PRNG are working (thread-safety, blocking and co.) where the more safe approach is using one PRNG for each thread/process (not sure what kind of parallelization is done here) and B: (in the case of different PRNGs) making sure that those seeds are able to produce good random-numbers. There are a lot of defects in many PRNGs in regards to this (e.g. Mersenne-Twister initialized with seeds: 0, 1, 2 -> bad). The keyword for further search is: *distributed seeding* (with many approaches: leap-frogging; PRNG-jumps, .).

Comment: Thanks. But all-purpose state-of-art packages [like `plyr`](https://github.com/hadley/plyr/blob/master/R/llply.r) do not seem to care about it. Does it mean that they should not be used for such purpose?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your worries are correct; random number generation does not magically work in parallel and further steps need to be taken.  When using the foreach framework, you can use the [doRNG](https://cran.r-project.org/package=doRNG) extension to make sure to get sound random numbers also when done in parallel.

Example:

```
library("doParallel")
cl <- makeCluster(2)
registerDoParallel(cl)

## Declare that parallel RNG should be used for in a parallel foreach() call.
## %dorng% will still result in parallel processing; it uses %dopar% internally.
library("doRNG")

y <- foreach(i = 1:100) %dorng% rnorm(1)
```

EDIT 2020-08-04: Previously this answer proposed the alternative:

```
library("doRNG")
registerDoRNG()
y <- foreach(i = 1:100) %dopar% rnorm(1)
```

However, the downside for that is that it is more complicated for the developer to use `registerDoRNG()` in a clean way inside functions.  Because of this, I recommend to use `%dorng%` to specify that parallel RNG should be used.

Comment: Thanks, +1. I heard about `doRNG` but never used it. Could you comment on how does using `registerDoRNG()` differ from using `%dorng%` ..? Are they the same?

Comment: I'm rusty on the details, but the doRNG vignette should answer your question.

Comment: By the way, does doFuture handle the RNG seeds anyhow?

Comment: No, doFuture is just a thin layer wrapping future into the foreach framework - it passes RNG needs on to foreach / doRNG.